# Why does OCaml need to create its own heaps for garbage collection?

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, ocaml

According to [this](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/understanding-the-garbage-collector.html#the-fast-minor-heap) OCaml's memory is contained in two contiguous chunks of virtual memory managed by the OCaml runtime. I would like to know why this is necessary. Couldn't OCaml simply use the system `malloc` to allocate memory, and only use these heaps to store the block headers and pointers to the object's actual home in memory? This seems like a reinvention of the wheel when the operating system can do so much of the work instead.

I would also like to know why OCaml must allocate an entirely new major heap during the `compact` phase of garbage collection ([source here](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/understanding-the-garbage-collector.html#the-long-lived-major-heap)), e.g.:

In the following rough sketch, let the letters `A`-`D` represent equally-sized pieces of OCaml blocks, and let `.` represent a freed space of the same size. From what I am given to understand, the OCaml garbage collector would "compact" this major heap:

```
[AAABB..CCCCCC.....DDD....]
```

By allocating a new major heap:

```
[.........................]
```

And copying the still-live blocks into it, before freeing the original heap:

```
[AAABBCCCCCCDDD...........]
```

How is this more efficient than simply rearranging those blocks inside the original heap? In the example above, a contiguity check could have avoided having to move blocks `A` and `B` at all, and in any case, how is it more efficient to ask the operating system to **always** allocate an entire new major heap?

Comment: this question is much better suited for OCaml mailing lists, where the design of a language can be discussed.

Comment: As I understand it, the main problem is that both a garbage collector and `malloc` must manage the memory they handle, and both do it opaquely, which means that if a GC were to do its handling using `malloc`, there would be 2 layers of memory management. You can see the overhead it incurs.

Comment: If the malloc internals were accessible (and standardised, as there are many implementations -- see for instance `jemalloc`), then _perhaps_ a GC like the one used in OCaml could be designed on top of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every garbage collector handle their own heap for performance reasons. `malloc` is a quite slow, and compared to OCaml minor heap allocation it is multiple orders of magnitude slower (an allocation in the minor heap is done in 2 assembly instructions).

For the compaction, no that doesn't reallocate.